How to blend camera when switching between 2 characters?
I'm trying to set up a system in UE4.27 where I can switch between 2 characters. It works but when I tried to include a camera blend, it still switches character but the camera just jumps and doesn't blend. Both of the characters have camera components with auto activation.
Any suggestions?


The Possess Pawn node is setting the camera immediately. So the Set View Target with Blend node is blending between the same points, i.e. not at all.
Move the Possess node to the end of the chain, after a new Delay node for 3 seconds, matching the blend time given in the Set View Target with Blend node.
The final camera blend position will be either at or extremely near the target position when the absolute camera jump from the Possess Pawn node occurs.
